# how to send data? from [AppwidgetProvider] to [Service]

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-service

//---MySimpleWidget.java---//

```
public class MySimpleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

.
.
.
        @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){
.
.
.

//from here

.
.
.
             }


}

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

...
}
```

//---service_test.java---//

```
public class service_test extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {    return null;    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    ...
    }
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        //here
    }

}
```

I`m an android beginner.
Please help me.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(context, service_test.class); context.startService(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put data into `Intent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, service_test.class); 
intent.putExtra("KEY","VALUE");
context.startService(intent);
```